# Variable combination in R

Tags: r, variables, combinations

i have two variables, both are  Factor Objects, Var1 has 3600 observations, Var 2 has 9000 observations, I want a Var3 that has those observations from Var2 that are found in Var1.

Maybe the title is misleading but I couldn't come up with anything else.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Maybe you mean that you have two datasets having at least a field in common (like an ID field)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question could benefit from some example data, but assuming I've interpreted you correctly, then you might be looking for the following:

```
var1 <- as.factor(c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A"))
var2 <- as.factor(c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D", "A", "K", "A"))

var3 <- var2[var2 %in% var1]

var3
# > var3
# [1] A B A A A A
# Levels: A B C D K
```

Comment: That's what i was just looking for. Thank you very much Alex.